# Navigation li Text Extend Outside the li rather than making second line ?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Drop Down navigation that I have created makes the text in li to go outside the li boundary rather than making second line.

How can I achieve so that li text goes down to next line ?

[image: Here is the picture of the li extended text, the annapurna base camp trek text]

and here is my code

```
#navigationSecond ul li ul{
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
width:182px;
list-style:none;
top:38px !important;
height:auto;
border-top:2px #FFF solid;
background:#FFF;
```

}

## navigationSecond ul li ul li{

```
float:none;

border-radius:6px;
padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
border:#FFF 1px solid;
margin:0 !important;
height:auto;
```

}

## navigationSecond ul li ul li a{

```
display:block;
padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;

color:#000;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:13px;
text-shadow:#FFF 0px 1px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
overflow:auto;
height:auto;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want the text goes outside the li and the li width are fixed means set a width for the li and it will be kept inside.

```
#navigationSecond ul li{width:120px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be use  `word-wrap: break-word;` for the text to display in next line. check this link http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Answer (score 0):

Please set a proper width for `li` tag.